# Erro segmentation fault(core dumped) em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, alocação, falha-de-segmentação

Ao tentar calcular qual o maior primo que pode fazer uma divisão de resto 0 com o número 600851475143 me deparei o erro segementation fault(core dumped) (embora tenha usado o crivo de eratóstenes para o cálculo de primos).  Já havia resolvido esse problema em outros algoritmos, mas não estou conseguindo nesse.

Acredito que o uso de alocação dinâmica vá ser fazer necessário, mas não me saí muito bem com isso. Segue código original.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int count_1 = 0, count_2 = 0, soma = 0, maior = 0;
  int numero_maximo[600851475144];

  for (count_1 = 2; count_1 <= 600851475143; count_1++)
  {
    numero_maximo[count_1] = count_1;
  }

  for (count_1 = 2; count_1 <= 600851475143; count_1++)
  {
    if (numero_maximo[count_1] == count_1)
    {
      if (600851475143 % count_1 == 0)
      {

        if (count_1 > maior)
        {
          maior = 0;
          maior = count_1;
        }
      }

    }
  }
  printf("%d\n", maior);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um int não comporta o número 600851475143. Pesquise por outros tipos de dados. Valor máximo aceitável por um int: 2147483647.

Comment: arranje uma máquina com mais de 600 GB de RAM :)
ou então crie um arquivo swap (para memória virtual) de mais de 600 GB de RAM (600GB é mais ou menos o tamanho do seu array "numero_maximo")...
ops, e precisa colocar como varável global, acho que nenhum sistema no mundo vai ter um stack de execução de 600GB...